# how to fix " is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I get a javascript file(such as gds.js), it's published from typescript. So, I have to add a *.d.ts file, when I want to use it in my angular project.

but I got the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: _gds__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.BPElementsService is not a constructor
```

The sample code from js file(gds.js):

```
(function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "BPElementsService", function() { return BPElementsService; });
/* harmony import */ var tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! tslib */ "../../node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js");
/* harmony import */ var _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/core */ "../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js");


var BPElementsService = /** @class */ (function () {
    function BPElementsService() {
        console.log("I am BPElementsService");
    }
    BPElementsService.prototype.sayHello = function () {
        console.log("Hello world");
    };
    BPElementsService = tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__decorate"]([
        Object(_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["Injectable"])(),
        tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__metadata"]("design:paramtypes", [])
    ], BPElementsService);
    return BPElementsService;
}());



/***/ })
```

gds.d.ts file is

```
export declare class BPElementsService {
constructor();
sayHello();}
```

Comment: `So, I have to add a *.d.ts file, when I want to use it in my angular project.` The library you're using doesn't ship its own `.d.ts` files? That doesn't sound right.